# Can we open an Lightning Component as a Tab within Lightning UI?

Tags: lightning-tab

For Lightning console app, we can open a lightning component in a new Tab using lightning:workspaceApi. Can we avail the same functionality without Lightning  Console app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this using following:

```
var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
      "recordId": "00QB0000000ybNX",
      "slideDevName": "related"
    });
    navEvt.fire();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes its is possible by using pageReference parameter of opentab() API in workspace API or you can use navigation service that will also work

WorkSpace api:`<lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>`

```
 let pageReference = {
                    type: 'standard__component',
                    attributes: {
                        componentName: 'c__componentname',
                    },
                    state: {
                        "parameter": 'hi'                                
                    }
                };   


workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
               let focusedTabId = response.tabId;

                                    workspaceAPI.openSubtab({parentTabId:focusedTabId,pageReference: pageReference,focus: true})

                                    .then(function(response) {workspaceAPI.focusTab({tabId: response});});

                                });
```

Navigation Api:    `<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>`

```
let navService = component.find("navService");
                            var pageReference = {
                                type: 'standard__component',
                                attributes: {
                                    "componentName": "c__componentname"
                                },
                                "state":{
                                    "parameter": 'hi'
                                }
                            };
                            navService.navigate(pageReference);
```

Comment: I have done this as per your suggestion. This is throwing following error.

null "Error: Could not locate focused tab."